# xray-rails not working with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, xray-rails

`xray-rails` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> is not working with Rails 4

**Gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'xray-rails'
end
```

**development.rb**

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

I bundled it

```
.
.
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using xray-rails 0.1.21
Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 68 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Inspecting the element in browser with <kbd>F12</kbd> shows me

```
<!--XRAY START 37 /home/sample/app/views/shared/_list.html.haml-->
<ol>
  <li>
    <strong>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </strong>
  </li>
</ol>
<!--XRAY END 37-->
```

**NOTE:** I am using `xray-rails` with rails 3.2 and it's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `xray.js` and `xray.css` fixed the issue

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require xray
```

**application.css**

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require xray
 */
```

Then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> worked as expected

[image: xray-rails]

Usually, the middleware inserts them automatically as said [here](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails#note-about-configassetsdebug)